# Visual C++ cannot compile vector insert()

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

C++ newbie here. I've finished doing a project using *Bloodshed Dev C++* and now I want to make it into a *Visual C++* project because I want to learn how to use *OpenGL* in it and most tutorials use the later for demonstration.

Although unfamiliar with it, I have used a `vector` to manage a dynamic array of pointers to objects, which led me to using `insert()` and `erase()` without having any knowledge of `iterator`s at all so don't be harsh with my question. The problem is the line where I insert a new item in vector using a calculated `int` to specify the position to be inserted (although I'm fairly sure that's not what's causing the compiler error -> see end of post). The line is (from here on I have replaced actual names with examples):

`vectorExample.insert(vectorExample.begin() + position, NULL);`

Everything compiles and works without any problem in *Dev C++* but in *Visual C++* when I try to compile this line I get the following errors (it compiles without it and program works for everything else):

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory(208): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'ClassExample *'
1>          Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory(280) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct<int>(ClassExample **,_Other &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=ClassExample *,
1>              _Other=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(668) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Cons_val<std::allocator<_Ty>,ClassExample*,int>(_Alloc &,_Ty1 *,_Ty2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=ClassExample *,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<ClassExample *>,
1>              _Ty1=ClassExample *,
1>              _Ty2=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(688) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<_Ty>::emplace_back<int>(_Valty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=ClassExample *,
1>              _Valty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(675) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> std::vector<_Ty>::emplace<int>(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>,_Valty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<ClassExample *,std::allocator<ClassExample *>>,
1>              _Ty=ClassExample *,
1>              _Valty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\user\desktop\mycppproject\mycppfile.cpp(412) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> std::vector<_Ty>::insert<int>(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>,_Valty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<ClassExample *,std::allocator<ClassExample *>>,
1>              _Ty=ClassExample *,
1>              _Valty=int
1>          ]
```

I have been looking at examples and searching for two days straight and I can't find anything similar to my problem. I also tried:

`vectorExample.insert(vectorExample.begin(), NULL);`

but I still get the exact same errors. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems you can't just plop a NULL in the place of a NULL pointer. Just guessing.

Comment: Damn, yeah actually the pointer is the problem. I just initialized a ClassExample *ptr = NULL; before the line and made it into vectorExample.insert(vectorExample.begin() + position, ptr); and it worked /facepalm

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
vectorExample.insert(vectorExample.begin() + position, nullptr);
```

In C++ NULL is defined as 0. So the template function can not convert int to a pointer.

Comment: I guess in retrospect that would be better than what I suggested.

Comment: @BWG I am not sure because not all compilers support nullptr yet.

Comment: It is also only supported in C++11, which not all compilers support yet.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 supports nullptr so this should be fine for the OP.

Comment: @drescherjm It is funny. Till now I thought that VC++ 2010 does not support nullptr. But now I test and indeed at least it compiles a code with nullptr.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a shot.

If you look at the definition of `NULL`, it is just `0` or `0L`. However, your vector accepts the type `ClassExample *`. While a pointer is essentially an int, you can't just put in an int. And `NULL` is just that, an int.

To fix this, I believe you could do something like:

```
ClassExample* p = NULL; //assigning a pointer to NULL (0) is alright
vectorExample.insert(vectorExample.begin() + position, p);
```

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is a define that maps to 0.  The compiler is telling you that it cannot implicitly convert an integer to a pointer:

> Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

So do what the compiler tells you to do:

```
vectorExample.insert(vectorExample.begin() + position, reinterpret_cast<ClassExample*>(NULL));
```

Or:

```
vectorExample.insert(vectorExample.begin() + position, (ClassExample*)NULL);
```